# UDP bind failures

Tags: c++, boost, mingw

{Windows 7, MinGW 4.8, boost 1.55}

I'm having some problems with UDP binds. I've a client that broadcasts datagrams for listeners listening on specific port and binds to a port itself if the listeners want to communicate something back. 
The port on which the client needs to bind is X and the servers are listening on Y.

Problem: 
If I simulate a client-crash (eg., by causing segmentation fault by dereferencing a nullptr) after binding the UDP socket to the port, then once the client application is no longer running (no longer listed in Windows Task Manager) netstat -ano | find "X" still shows that someone is bound to port **X** and ip address of 0.0.0.0 (the client had specified the IP address as any address). The PID cannot be found in Windows Task Manager. However when I downloaded application TCPView I can see that a `<non-existent>` process is still bound to 50000. On starting the client (without making it crash this time) subsequently.

I get two behaviors:

<1> On some machines the client is unable to bind to the socket again (although reuse_address option is set to true) and the error message is: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.

<2> On other machines the client binds successfully but the read handler is not called and the client does not receive any datagram on port X although the servers are unicasting to the client port X. Infact <2> is true even for launching multiple instances of the client on the same machine even if none of the clients were deliberately made to crash and exist as zombie processes. Only the 1st one gets datagrams.

Here is how client socket is set up:

```
if(!m_udpSocket.is_open()) 
   { 
      m_udpSocket.open(m_localEndpoint.protocol(), errorCode); //m_localEndpoint is address 0.0.0.0 and port X 
      if(errorCode) 
      { 
         std::cerr << "Unable to open socket: " << errorCode.message() << std::endl; 
      } 
      else 
      { 
         m_udpSocket.set_option(boost::asio::socket_base::reuse_address(true), errorCode); 
         if(errorCode) 
         { 
            std::cerr << "Reuse address option set failure. " << errorCode.message() << std::endl; 
         } 

         m_udpSocket.set_option(boost::asio::socket_base::broadcast(true), errorCode); 
         if(errorCode) 
         { 
            std::cerr << "Socket cannot send broadcast. " << errorCode.message() << std::endl; 
         } 
         else 
         { 
            m_udpSocket.bind(m_localEndpoint, errorCode); 
            if(errorCode) 
            { 
               std::cerr << "Socket cannot bind...!! " << errorCode.message() << std::endl; 
            } 
         } 
      } 
   }
```

Can you explain why do I get <1> and <2> and what can I do to avoid them and make socket bind even if there is some other process bound to that socket? I need to support Windows, Linux and MAC.

Comment: of-course the socket can be bound the second time. That's what boost::asio::socket_base::reuse_address(true) is there for and that's why you have <2> above where the binding is successful. As for the process, did you read the question carefully - It's not listed in Windows Task Manager, sort of a zombie process.

Comment: Well, your question looks to be answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14388706/socket-options-so-reuseaddr-and-so-reuseport-how-do-they-differ-do-they-mean-t